# After using create-react-app, any packages I install break my code?

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I created a sample app with `create-react-app`, I start my project and used `npm install prop-types` to install the package. I got a bunch of warnings:

```
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/.bin/jest as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/jest
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/.bin/regjsparser as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/regjsparser
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/.bin/jsesc as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/jsesc
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/.bin/esparse as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/esprima
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/esprima
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/.bin/cssesc as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/cssesc
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/.bin/acorn as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/acorn-globals/node_modules/acorn
npm WARN rm not removing /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/@babel/generator/node_modules/.bin/jsesc as it wasn't installed by /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample/node_modules/@babel/generator/node_modules/jsesc
```

And when I ran `npm start` I got the following errors:

```
> sample@0.1.0 start /Users/carlosgrijalva/Programming/sample
> react-scripts start

sh: react-scripts: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! sample@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sample@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/carlosgrijalva/.npm/_logs/2018-11-02T15_33_21_597Z-debug.log
```

Below are the my versions for npm, node, and create-react app

`node --version: v8.10.0`

`create-react-app --version: 2.0.4`

`npm --version: 5.6.0`

I have a feeling that the problem is with having both Yarn and NPM installed? Not sure though, anyone ran through this issue?

Comment: by default, it will prefer yarn during CRA install so try `yarn add prop-types` and `yarn start`

Comment: One simple question... Look that your folder where you are running npm install is correct, probably when you want to run npm from folder that hasn't got package.json will throw you this error, Try to run npm install from root folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having both Yarn and NPM installed is fine and won't lead to any problems.Actually many projects will both have yarn and npm to make it easier for more users.

"sh: react-scripts: command not found":About this problem,maybe your node_modules didn't work well.

So,delete your node_modules,and npm **npm install** again.

And about the warning, you should add a package with **npm install prop-types --save  instead of npm install prop-types**.

Comment: Ah of course.

I ended up just running `npm install` and then `npm start` and now it seems to be working. I'm just wondering if this is something that will be recurring after installing any other packages.

Comment: @user7496931 to save you from future headaches, use yarn instead of npm. Your problem most likely stemmed from installing npm in the wrong directory and you do not have enough admin rights to run npm from that directory.

Comment: @user7496931 I don't think this is something that will be recurring after installing any other packages.This problem maybe happened when your network isn't so well or other solutions that your packages didn't install correct.And the comment upstairs is right, use yarn maybe a better option,